Problemas con el build del gradle
Tengo un archivo para el gradle build pero no me funciona ya que me salta el siguiente error:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'koalamarket'.
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:3.2.4.
Required by:
project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.2.4 > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.4
> Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:3.2.4.
> Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-buildpack-platform/3.2.4/spring-boot-buildpack-platform-3.2.4.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-buildpack-platform/3.2.4/spring-boot-buildpack-platform-3.2.4.pom'.
> Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
> Connect to localhost:3128 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:3.2.4.
Required by:
project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.2.4 > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.4
> Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:3.2.4.
> Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/3.2.4/spring-boot-loader-tools-3.2.4.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/3.2.4/spring-boot-loader-tools-3.2.4.pom'.
> Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
> Connect to localhost:3128 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21.
Required by:
project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.2.4 > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.4
> Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21.
> Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.21/commons-compress-1.21.pom'.
> Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.21/commons-compress-1.21.pom'.
> Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
> Connect to localhost:3128 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
Could not resolve org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.10.
Required by:
project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.2.4 > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.4
> Could not resolve org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.10.
> Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.10/spring-core-6.0.10.pom'.
> Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.10/spring-core-6.0.10.pom'.
> Got socket exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
> Connect to localhost:3128 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.kotlinkoalas'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'KoalamarketApplication'
}

test {
    enabled = false
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task getDeps(type: Copy) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from configurations.compileClasspath into "libs/"
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath into "libs/"
}



Tengo puesto el java 19 y la versión del gradle 8.7
